# Count Total Transaction each specific row even if 0

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a 3 Columns namely:

1. `Payment Channel`
2. `Payment Name`
3. `Total Transaction`

The `Total Transaction` will be the **COUNT** of each `Payment Channel` and `Payment Name`.

In the `Payment Channel`, values have `PC01`-`PC09`.

I want my result to display all the `Payment Channel` even if no transactions.

**Here is my SQL Script:**

```
SELECT
    B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL AS Payment_Channel,
    COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME AS Payment_Name,
    COUNT(B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID) AS Total_Transaction
FROM B2C_BUY_LOG
INNER JOIN B2C_BUY_HIST ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID = B2C_BUY_HIST.PAY_ID
INNER JOIN COMM_CODE ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL = COMM_CODE.CODE
WHERE B2C_BUY_LOG.RET_CODE = 1
AND B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID LIKE '190220%'
AND COMM_CODE.CODE IN('PC01', 'PC02', 'PC03', 'PC04', 'PC05', 'PC06', 'PC07', 'PC08', 'PC09')
GROUP BY Payment_Channel, Payment_Name;
```

**Here is the result of my Query:**

```
Payment_Channel   Payment_Name    Total_Transaction
PC01              Name-1          14
PC02              Name-2          2
PC03              Name-3          7
PC04              Name-4          9
PC06              Name-6          21
PC08              Name-8          18
PC09              Name-9          95
```

This query returns only the match values between the joined tables because it is **INNER JOIN** and the **PC05** and **PC07** is missing on the result because it has no transaction. I also tried different **JOINS**.

How can I display the `PC05` and `PC07` with a count of **0** if no transaction?

Thanks!

Comment: I already used LEFT JOIN but it doesn't show also

Comment: Put your `WHERE` criteria into the `ON` and then `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: is there actually `PC05` and `PC07` in the data set that match the crieria

Comment: what do you mean @danblack

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    channels.channel AS Payment_Channel,
    COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME AS Payment_Name,
    COUNT(B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID) AS Total_Transaction
FROM (           SELECT 'PC01' channel 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC02' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC03' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC04' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC05' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC06' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC07' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC08' 
       UNION ALL SELECT 'PC09') channels
LEFT JOIN B2C_BUY_LOG ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL = channels.channel
LEFT /* or INNER */ JOIN B2C_BUY_HIST ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID = B2C_BUY_HIST.PAY_ID
INNER /* or LEFT */ JOIN COMM_CODE ON B2C_channels.channel = COMM_CODE.CODE
WHERE B2C_BUY_LOG.RET_CODE = 1
AND B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID LIKE '190220%'
GROUP BY Payment_Channel, Payment_Name;
```

Comment: I tried this but the PC05 and PC07 doesn't show. Also, tried with the COUNT(COMM_CODE.CODE) AS Total_Transaction, didnt work

Comment: @Cyril *PC05 and PC07 is missing on the result because it has no transaction* Does this mean there is no those codes in B2C_BUY_LOG table? If so you need a synthetic base table (or maybe such table which stores all codes already exists?) contained all codes you need to show as a base table. On that step specify MySQL version in your question (proper tagging recommended).

Comment: there is value in the COMM_CODE.CODE table. The PC05 and PC07 is there, the COMM_CODE.CODE table and B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL is fk

Comment: @Cyril Check the edited variant. Non-commented join variants seems to be preferable, but it must be checked due to a logic unknown to me.

Comment: its syntax error

Comment: @Cyril If there is an error, you must to quote the error message, not to say that it occured only.

Comment: sorry. SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.PG_CHANNEL       UNION ALL 'PGC02'       UNION ALL 'PGC03'       UNION AL' at line 5

Comment: @Cyril *`.PG_CHANNEL UNION ALL`* No such fragment in MY query (pay attention to a dot). Be more careful when adjusting the query text to your data structure.

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''PGC02'        UNION ALL 'PGC03'        UNION ALL 'PGC04'        UNION ALL' at line 6

Comment: @Cyril Nobody can debug a query without seeing it. Create a fiddle.

Comment: (I fixed the syntax error)